How to fix missing spans in Signoz using an AWS lambda function

I am trying to implement Signoz (https://signoz.io/) and running signoz locally(as shown in image). I am able to get traces but getting missing spans in traces. I am using AWS Lambda function using API Gateway and Application load balancer and running an Express app.
I am using https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-lambda/tree/main/nodejs this and added as a layer in AWS Lambda function.
collector.yaml
receivers:
  otlp:
    protocols:
      http:
        endpoint: "localhost:4318"

exporters:
  otlphttp:
    endpoint: "https://ccde-49-205-251.ngrok-free.app"
    retry_on_failure:
      enabled: true
      initial_interval: 10s
      max_interval: 30s
      max_elapsed_time: 300s
    tls:
      insecure: true
    timeout: 30s 
    
processors:
  batch:
    timeout: 5s
    send_batch_size: 512
    send_batch_max_size: 1024
  memory_limiter:
    check_interval: 1s
    limit_mib: 2000
    spike_limit_mib: 500
    ballast_size_mib: 250

service:
  pipelines:
    traces:
      receivers: [otlp]
      processors: [batch, memory_limiter]
      exporters: [otlphttp]
    metrics:
      receivers: [otlp]
      processors: [batch]
      exporters: [otlphttp]
    logs:
      receivers: [otlp]
      processors: [batch]
      exporters: [otlphttp]

AWS function > Configuration > Environment variables
AWS_LAMBDA_EXEC_WRAPPER = /opt/otel-handler
OPENTELEMETRY_COLLECTOR_CONFIG_FILE = /var/task/collector.yaml
OTEL_LAMBDA_DISABLE_AWS_CONTEXT_PROPAGATION = true


Are you getting any error in lambda logs related to export spans ?
can you also enable logging exporter in otel collector and see are you getting spans from lambda?
